# How can I use the result returned in a delegate method to fire a callback in React-Native (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

So I'm in a bit of a pickle here...

I'm creating an application that requires me to use an awkward SDK for a specific hardware api - and to get the status of anything, rather than return a value it fires off a delegate method where the value is accessible there as an argument for the delegate method.  This is making callbacks to React-Native a challenge.

Here is my basic method being called from React:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openSirenAlarm: (RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback)
{
  cameraControl.cameraSiren.delegate = self;
  [cameraControl.cameraSiren playCameraSiren];
  callback(@[@(error), @(response)]);
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(closeSirenAlarm: (RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback)
{
  cameraControl.cameraSiren.delegate = self;
  [cameraControl.cameraSiren stopCameraSiren];
  callback(@[@(error), @(response)]);
}
```

And here are the delegate methods provided in the SDK:

```
#pragma mark CameraSirenDelegate
- (void) cameraSiren:(CameraSiren *)cameraSiren stopResult:(ENUM_APP_RESULT)result
{
  NSLog(@"stop result: %u", result);
    if (result == RESULT_SUCCESS)
    {
      NSLog(@"stop success");
      error = 0;
      response = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      error = 1;
      response = 0;
    }
}
- (void) cameraSiren:(CameraSiren *)cameraSiren playResult:(ENUM_APP_RESULT)result
{
  NSLog(@"start result: %u", result);
    if (result == RESULT_SUCCESS)
    {
      NSLog(@"start success");
      error = 0;
      response = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      error = 1;
      response = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm having a couple issues:

As you can see, I'm setting the error result in the delegate methods, but the callback fires right away (including before they're even set the first time) - so at best they're one action behind in terms of information.

I've played with `RCTEventEmitters` but I find them to be generally sloppy and unreliable - generally firing at least twice and causing me a bit of a headache (if this is a common thing that anyone can help me with I'd gladly use emission).

Is there an obvious way to do this that I'm missing, or a smarter design pattern to handle this?

Comment: You should absolutely go with RCTEventEmitters, if you get it right it should work perfectly.

Comment: Ok - I'll continue that way, and work on discovering why it's consistently firing each event twice.